# How do I make my background change images automatically every 15 seconds? JavaScript? jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know this sounds simple and I searched up and down the web for a script but cant find anything. I just want my backgrounds to change every 15 seconds or so automatically. (like a photo slide show but as a background.)
My style sheet is controls the bg image in the body tag.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval), you can call an arbitrary function in, well, intervals:

```
(function() {
    var curImgId = 0;
    var numberOfImages = 42; // Change this to the number of background images
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image','url(/background' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
        curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
    }, 15 * 1000);
})();
```

Comment: Assumes an infinite number of background images?  :)

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. :) i need help applying this to my page. Can you point me to some kind of instructions on installation? Thank you both for the help. Do i put this inside a <script> tag on my html?

Comment: @Fab Installation? Just put this into the JavaScript code of your page, i.e. in the `.js` file or between `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>`. Can you elaborate on what you need help with?

Comment: well im sorry to bother with a million questions. i'm trying this now. I would like to understand how to write code. thanks for your help. are you available for tutoring? I want to learn but i need a little more help than a textbook. I'm willing to pay you for your time :) i really want to learn javascript, jquery, php (i know html and css somewhat) brb- going to try your script

Comment: @Fab No problem, we love to answer questions here ;). If you have any questions or just want to talk about programming, feel free to contact me via [icq, Jabber, or email](http://phihag.de).

Comment: @Fab Oops, there was a bug in the previous version that induces a compile error. Fixed now. Sorry!

Comment: @phihag i cant get this to work. I dont know what im doing wrong. can you give me a step by step please. No background appears.

Comment: @Fab First, put the background files into a reachable directory (test that you can access one in your browser). Then, set up an HTML and  jQuery (i.e. [download jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js)) and add `<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>`. Then, add the above Javascript in a new `<script>` element under that. Can you somehow contact me via instant messenger or [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) or so?

Comment: ok working now!! :) thank you.. I didnt know about the jquery link. thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple enough to do with [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```
var currentIndex = 1;
var totalCount = 21;

setInterval(function() {
    if (currentIndex > totalCount)
        currentIndex = 1;

    $(body).css('background-image', 'url(/bg' + currentIndex++ + '.jpg)');
}, 15000);
```

Comment: can you please explain to me how this code works?  the body tag is in a seperate .css file (style.css)  so would this be: 

setInterval(function() {
  $(body)style.css('background-image', 'url(/myimage.jpg)');
}, 15000);

Comment: @Kon w3schools is a [notoriously unreliable source](http://w3fools.com/); it's name is misleading as it is not associated with the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/).

Comment: @Fab The css file does not matter, this directly sets CSS in the DOM tree (overwriting the defaults in the css file)

Comment: @phihag Regardless of your opinions of the site, it provides correct info in this particular case, which is more than I can say about your original answer which incorrectly switched the code and interval parameters, and the subsequent updates that basically copied from my answer.

Comment: dreamweaver is giving me a syntax error:function() {
    var curImgId = 1;
    var numberOfImages = 4; // Change this to the number of background images
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('body').css('bg','url(/images/bg' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
        curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
    }, 15 * 1000); 
 }();

Comment: @Kon, im trying your script- I cant get it to work. I need a little help please. my bg images are named "bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4" all jpeg. How do i set this script up? Before the </head> in my index.html file? Does the url point to my image folder? or to bg1?

do i need to change the image names to "0, 1, 2, 3"?

Comment: If you can access your bg image like this:  /bg1.jpg then it should work the way my example shows (updated).

Comment: yes i can access my bg at /bg1.jpg from root however the script is not working. ? How do i fix?

Comment: @Kon I don't know what I should've copied in the first place (to which lines are you referring to?), but note that your answer is CC licensed and can therefore be copied. I'm not sure how *I* could have copied the image index, which your second update added 6 minutes *after* my first answer contained it. Also note that there are significant differences between our answers now; my last update does not pollute the global namespace anymore, and uses the modulo operator instead of an additional if statement.

Comment: @Fab I'd love to help you with the code to fix that. Can you contact me or Kon via instant messenger, VNC, or [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script style="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var curImgId = 0;
        var numberOfImages = 5; // Change this to the number of background images
        window.setInterval(function() {
            $('body').css('background','url("'+ curImgId +'.jpg")');// set the image path here
            curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
        }, 15 * 1000);
    })();

</script>
```