# I want my body background image to fade in and fade out every 5 seconds, if not atleast change every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, background

I have found [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6808072/35070) but haven't been able to adapt it to my website.
I'm new to HTML, JavaScript and CSS, so bear with me.

I want my background  to change from `bg0.jpg` to `bg1.jpg` to `bg2.jpg` and then back to `bg0.jpg`.

I'm working on dreamweaver.

My source code is linking to jquery.js and imagefader.js.

My style.css file is also linked to my source code.

the css file applies the body background image:

```css
body {
  background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/bg0.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:center;
}
```

my imagefader.js has the following content:

```
(function() {
  var curImgId = 0;
  var numberOfImages = 3; // Change this to the number of background images
  window.setInterval(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image','url(/background' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
    curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
  }, 5 * 1000);
})();
```

The problem is that changes from bg0.jpg to a white background after 5 seconds instead of bg1.jpg.

The result can be seen here.
http://mrinalikamath.in

Please help me modify the files so that i get the required result.

Comment: That’s quite alright!

Answer (score 3):

The path is wrong.

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(/background' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
```

Your images are in ../images/backgrouds/ and the first attempt tries the URL http://mrinalikamath.in/background0.jpg .

However, you want http://mrinalikamath.in/images/backgrounds/bg0.jpg :

```
 $('body').css('background-image','url(/images/backgrounds/bg' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
```

I can't recommend Fiddler enough to help with problems like this. It shows every http request from your browser so you can see 404s.

http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: could you please edit the java script for me? what should i change in it?

Comment: I did - check my revision.

Comment: Note that fiddler is not necessary, your browser's development tools suffice for this kind of simple problem. Simply press `F12`, and go to the network tab (you may have to reload the site after that).

Comment: Good point. Chrome's network tab is great. I just prefer using a separate tool like fiddler but your suggestion is valid.

Comment: I copy pasted your revised code in my js file and it still doesnt show the required result.It still shows the blank white background after 5 seconds. Is this how it is supposed to be? $('body').css('background-image','linktofirstbackgroundimage' + curImgId + 'linktosecondbackgroundimage');

Comment: @MrinaliKamath Can you upload the new version of the JavaScript file? The [current online version](http://mrinalikamath.in/java%20script/imageFader.js) is still the old one.

Comment: I'm checking the results through dreamweaver, preview in browser option

Comment: @MrinaliKamath No, you can just copy the line from the answer verbatim, no need to change anything. In the code, you want the pattern, so literally `url(/images/background/bg' + curImgId + '.jpg)'`.

Comment: Okay so this is my current java script:(function() {
  var curImgId = 0;
  var numberOfImages = 2; // Change this to the number of background images
  window.setInterval(function() {
 $('body').css('background-image','url(/images/backgrounds/bg' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
  }, 5 * 1000);
})();

Comment: I just checked the url of the file - http://mrinalikamath.in/java%20script/imageFader.js - it still has the original url - please upload the file with the changes I suggested.

Comment: The old version is still at that URL.

Comment: http://mrinalikamath.in i uploaded the file, this time it did change the background image but its shows a blank white screen for a second during transition..can that be fixed?

Comment: It is because the images need to be preloaded. Check out this jsbin - I think it is a nicer way to fade through these. http://jsbin.com/icokaf/1/edit  Please accept the answer if this works for you.